# Outside access to Facebook events

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk

Let's say I own/control a Facebook page where events are posted. I'd like to display these events on another website (In my case, a WordPress blog, but that's not the important part) on an "Upcoming events" page.

What I'm unsure about is: Is the Facebook API usable "externally" like this? I've downloaded the PHP library and have a demo app running that works *from within Facebook* (i.e. emitting FBML that facebook.com interprets and displays to the logged-in user), but in my case I want a third party (my web server) to query Facebook every so often, rather than the site visitors directly requesting data (HTML/JSON/etc.) from Facebook itself.

Is this sort of thing possible with the Facebook API? How will my web server authenticate itself? What information do I have to store?

Note: I'm looking for information more at a "sequence diagram" conceptual level, not just asking for code. That part I can figure out myself. ;) Unfortunately, Google and the FB developer wiki have not been entirely forthcoming. What do I need to know so I can start coding?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you had any luck with this, I am trying to implement a simple version similar to yours and was curious about what method you ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a basic overview of how I've done it for a few of my clients who wanted similar functionality:

1. Create a pretty basic app that prompts for [Extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Extended_Permissions/), specifically "offline_access" and whatever else you need
2. Store the resulting [Session Key](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorizing_Applications#About_Session_Keys) in your database with the [UID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)
3. Create a secure, authenticated webservice for your app which allows you to get the info you need for a UID that you supply, using the session that you've stored in your database
4. On the website make requests to your app's webservice, being sure to cache the results for a certain period of time and only make a new request to your webservice once the cache has expired (I use 5-10 minutes for most of mine)

So basically your Facebook app acts sort of like a proxy between the website and the user, doing all of the authenticating and requesting using legitimate means.

I've used a webservice because I only wanted to maintain one Facebook app for multiple client's needs. It works like this (in a not-very-awesome ASCII art diagram):

```
Facebook User 1 \                    / Client Website 1
Facebook User 2  --- Facebook App ---  Client Website 2
Facebook User 3 /                    \ Client Website 3
```

***Note:*** I've only done this for users, not pages, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: is the webservice adding much value in this set up?

Comment: I've used a webservice in my case because I have multiple clients using the one Facebook app, and those same clients' websites talking to the Facebook app to display the data on their own sites. If the website and the app were one in the same then you could eliminate the web service bit. As I said in my answer, this is just MY setup. Brant could do something similar and eliminate the bits he doesn't require.

Comment: thanks, just curious - thought you might see some speed improvements by caching locally with the webservice, but seems like a lot of added complexity if you're not pulling a lot of data.

Comment: It would definitely add another layer of complexity that's not particularly required in this case. If the app & webservice was in use for a large number of users & websites then I'd definitely consider adding caching!

Comment: I'm definitely going for a simple solution here, so I'll probably skip the web service bit, but this is useful information. For a while I thought I'd have to use Facebook Connect to do this sort of thing, I'm glad to see that there's a solution that just makes use of the basic Platform.

Answer (score 4):

You can do [Events.get](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Events.get) with the Facebook API then supply the page/profile ID you'd like to get the events for. Depending on how your page is setup you may have to authenticate, simply use your Facebook account, since you should have access to all the events. oh and make sure you do plenty of caching so your not hitting Facebook on every page load.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK other than user info, you can't fetch any other data from facebook.

But you can try it other way - say create an app that stores events and other relevant information on a webserver and then your other website can easily access that info.